# Create application page on O365

Tags: codebehind

I have created an aspx page for login to O365. I then found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10211697/2083526) saying you cannot have .cs code behind files on SharePoint that you should reference an assembly.

I am assuming the assembly in this case would be my project dll, but where do you add this assembly in O365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint online you cannot add any SharePoint Server Object model code. You have below options:

1. Convert the code to JavaScript,upload it to style library and create a page in Pages or
   SitePages library and refer javascript file in script editor/content editor web part.
2. Create [SharePoint hosted app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx) for the functionality(Javascript CSOM).
3. Create a [Provider hosted App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx) (Managed CSOM).

Update: The recommendation now a days is to use [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)